# My MikTeX2.9 installation bombs out when attempting to update

Tags: miktex-update

When attempting to update the wizard downloads the files but then informs me that the operation was unsuccessful. Not seeing a way of attaching the logfile I'll paste its content below (and grudgingly bear the risk of being ridiculed and shouted at by the TeX.SX community):

```
2017-10-05 15:31:58,382+1100 INFO  Update - starting: Update Wizard (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
2017-10-05 15:32:42,478+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - starting package maintenance...
2017-10-05 15:32:42,478+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - installation directory: "C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9"
2017-10-05 15:32:42,478+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - package repository: http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2017-10-05 15:32:42,478+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - visiting repository http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2017-10-05 15:32:42,478+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - repository type: remote package repository
2017-10-05 15:32:42,478+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - loading lightweight database...
2017-10-05 15:32:42,478+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - downloading http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2017-10-05 15:32:44,316+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 170962 bytes, 90.98 KB/Sec
2017-10-05 15:32:44,463+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - lightweight database digest: 4a34497ea314c7604da421b7260fe17b
2017-10-05 15:32:44,463+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'mpm --register-components --verbose'
2017-10-05 15:32:44,748+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - problem: C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fontconfig\config\fonts.conf.in does not exist
2017-10-05 15:32:44,780+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --update-fndb --verbose'
2017-10-05 15:32:45,620+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory ("C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9")...
2017-10-05 15:32:45,666+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Creating fndb for user root directory ("C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9")...
2017-10-05 15:32:45,666+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-10-05 15:32:49,356+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-10-05 15:32:49,372+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'
2017-10-05 15:32:49,541+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-10-05 15:32:49,541+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.
2017-10-05 15:32:49,541+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-10-05 15:32:49,541+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
2017-10-05 15:32:49,541+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-10-05 15:32:49,541+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage -   C:/Users/Reinhard Neuwirth/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log
2017-10-05 15:32:49,541+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-10-05 15:32:49,557+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
2017-10-05 15:32:49,557+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - 
2017-10-05 15:32:49,557+1100 INFO  FileCopyPage - Error: The executed process did not succeed.

initexmf.log:

2017-10-06 16:30:10,567+1100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
2017-10-06 16:30:10,598+1100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory ("C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9")...
2017-10-06 16:30:13,559+1100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for user root directory ("C:\Users\Reinhard Neuwirth\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9")...
2017-10-06 16:30:13,762+1100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2017-10-06 16:30:13,762+1100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2017-10-06 16:30:17,481+1100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
2017-10-06 16:30:17,528+1100 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

2017-10-06 16:30:17,528+1100 FATAL initexmf - Info: existing="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdfclose.exe", new="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdfclose.exe.(old)"
2017-10-06 16:30:17,528+1100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2017-10-06 16:30:17,528+1100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 301
```

Comment: And was does the initexmf.log say?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited the question to include the initexmf.log

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Reinhard Neuwirth,

Looks like you got a Windows error code 5: Access denied.  Please try running the update package with the Run as Administrator option.

Comment: `MikTeX Update(Admin)` completed successfully, but `MikTeX Package Manager(Admin)` showed that the installed versions of packages had not been replaced. I am about to throw the towel.